# Converting equation to $y = mx + b$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

My sister have an assignment of converting below equation to slope as $y = mx + b$

$xy = 4$

Can anyone help? thanks in advance. ^_^

Comment: It is not all clear what you mean by "converting equation to $y=mx+b".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not possible.

Look at the [graph of xy=4](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=xy=4). You will notice that it is hyperbola, not a line. Your sister will therefore be unable to write it in the form $y=mx+b$, which would be a straight line.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. :)